# I'm using geocoder to get latitude,longitude and address by giving name of a place.How to iterate over the dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, latitude-longitude

I'm using geocoder to get latitude,longitude and address by giving name of a place.How to iterate over the dataframe column

code to calculate latitude and longitude of place name when defined:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

To make it easy and understandable you could have shown the head of your Dataframe to see the columns.

to itegrate through a dataFrame:

```
for column in df:
    print(df[column])
```

or you can use `iteritems()`

```
for name, values in df.iteritems():
    print('{name}: {value}'.format(name=name, value=values[0]))
```

Another workaround is to transpose the DataFrame and iterate over the rows.

```
for column_name, column in df.transpose().iterrows():
    print(column_name)
```

We can use Python's list slicing easily to slice df.columns according to our needs. For eg, to iterate over all columns but the first one, we can do:

```
for column in df.columns[1:]:
    print(df[column])
```

Comment: title
rating
category
description
these are the columns in the dataframe.